# while and IF controller- Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I have a While controller with condition

```
${__javaScript("${DONE}"!="Downloaded")}
```

which works perfect.

Now I want to add another condition

```
${__javaScript("${Temp}"!="No Exceptions found")}
```

loop must quit in one of the above conditions.

For this I added an "If Controller" as a child of While Controller and give this condition( `${__javaScript("${Temp}"!="No Exceptions found")}` ) in If Controller but did not get how to quit the loop.

What to do to quit this loop in case it finds "No Exceptions found" if it did not find "Downloaded" first?

Moreover Jmeter is generating error in .log file on evaluating If Condition, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What exception is generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to put If Controller inside While Controller. You can use this condition in While Controller:

```
${__javaScript("${DONE}"!="Downloaded" && "${Temp}"!="No Exceptions found")}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm for me!  Initially, set wrong logical operation: "||"  instead of expected &&. Spent 2+ hrs to find out what I missed :(